# How to eliminate text AssertionError: expected response to have status code 400 but got 200 in Postman?

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I am using Postman to test the APIs. When I send an API for the test, result displays in the test result section e.g Status Code is 400

> First name cannot be empty
>   | AssertionError: expected response to
>   have status code 400 but got 200.

I just want to eliminate text

> | AssertionError: expected response to have status code 400 but got
>   200.

I readout the documentation for this issue, but didn't get any solution.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var firstName   = "";

// ***************************** Firstname ********************

// Check first name is Empty
if(firstName===null || firstName===undefined ){
pm.test("Status Code is 400 First name cannot be empty", function(){
    pm.response.to.have.status(400);
});
```

Comment: Is there more code that you're not adding to the question - `dkjsdckhkdjhcsdkjchsdjkhcsjkdhcksjdchjxchjhjdhcjksdhckjsdhcjkhsdjkchsdjcsjhdcxdft is Greater than 32 characters | ...` Would be the Test Name and as per your code wouldn't result in that error. Is there an else condition or another test?

Comment: @DannyDainton Typo, read my question again .

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. The way to remove the assertion error, is by having a test that passes either that or by adding an `else` to that `if` statement to go down a different path if either of those 2 conditions are not met.